# TensorFlow 2 keras model training very slow on CPU and most cpu cores (>95% cores) are idle

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0, cpu

I am trying to train a neural network model (TensorFlow 2.8) on a CPU (EC2 instance m4.10 with about 160GB and 40 CPU cores) from the Jupyter notebook. The training data is loaded from 300+ gzip files (each file is 200+ MB) and processed as a dataset. But, the training process is very slow. It cost 75 mins per epoch.
The code:

```
 import tensorflow.keras as keras
 tf.comfig.run_function_eagerly(True)
 model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate), loss=keras.BinaryCrossEntropy),
               run_eagerly=True,
               metrics=[keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])

 model.fit(train_data, epoch=10, steps_per_epoch=1000, validation_steps=100, 
          workers=16, use_muiltiprocessing=True)
```

When the model is being trained, only 1 or 2 CPU cores are busy and all other 38 cores are idle.

I have tried `eager=False`, but no use. I have checked some posts about why `tf2` is slower than `tf1`, but, none of them talk about why most CPU cores are idle.

Please let me know what I missed here?

Comment: You can try setting maximum workers `workers=psutil.cpu_count()`.  However, DNN models are supposed to be trained on GPU.

Comment: @M.Innat, thanks for your reply. I have tried this. but still most cores are idle.

Comment: This just means that compute is not your bottleneck, might be data loading or something else.